# Excel datasource in JasperReports/iReport: Unable to get value for field 'Date' of class 'java.sql.Date'

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, ireport

I've used an *Excel* file as datasource for building report with *iReport*. The *xls* file contains dates ***yyyy-MM-dd*** format.

I've set the Date field class to *java.sql.Date* and I click on preview in *iReport*. There is an error: `Unable to get value for field 'Date' of class 'java.sql.Date'.`

I have tried with *java.util.Date* too. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it is maybe a duplicate, but there is no answer which is working. Also a cannot find a solution on Google.

Comment: @Daniel `I have dates in Excel in yyyy-MM-dd format. I import it to iReport` - What do you mean?

Comment: @pnuts Yes, I have tried it, it is not working either.
Still, in Excel there is `=TEXT(A2,"yyyy-mm-dd")` etc. In iReport, there is custom date format yyyy-MM-dd. Field class java.util.Date or java.sql.Date are not working.

Comment: @AlexK I create a database connection in iReport using .xlsx file as source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite simple.

I've *xls* file (*birhdays.xls*) like this:

[image]

The datasource definition (in *iReport*) is:

[image]

As you can see from the image above I've set *`yyyy-MM-dd`* format for date field in *DS* definition.

The *date field* definition in *jrxml* file:

```xml
<field name="Birthday" class="java.util.Date"/>
```

The full *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="excel_ds" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="b0f82d57-325b-4c30-b635-f464851e0a47">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Birthday" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="cd75f6d9-1781-4938-bf24-178b6663bcd1" x="0" y="0" width="147" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="5d4c21f1-9afd-40c7-ade0-6fcc0b3d8373" x="147" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Birthday]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="82f5a338-ef5d-4838-8cd0-c2544af3a73d" x="0" y="0" width="147" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
                <reportElement uuid="e6eb6f83-b8f3-42fd-b116-02db2322b6a5" x="147" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Birthday}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

And the result will be (via preview in *iReport*):

[image]

*Note*:

I've used *iReport 5.1.0*

Comment: Thank you, this is a great solution. I have tried many similar. A last question: can I handle different date types (for example yyyy-mm-dd and yyyy/mm/dd) at the same time in iReport?

Comment: You are welcome :) The answer on your additional question is "No, you can not". For details look at my answer on your [Jasper iReport custom date and custom time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18269626/876298) question ;)