# Jasper iReport custom date and custom time

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, ireport

In Excel, I have a date format yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm and a time format hh:mm. I set this as a source for an iReport database.

For the date I set a custom date format in iReport, same as in Excel. Then I set **class="java.util.Date"**.

For the time, which class should I choose? I've tried many, none working.

I think, the problem is, that I cannot set another custom date format, so the iReport does not recognise it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Some people told be before, that in Excel, every column must be text, not anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite slightly harder to solve this your new case than the old one described in [Excel datasource in JasperReports/iReport: Unable to get value for field 'Date' of class 'java.sql.Date'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18258850/876298) post.

### Solution

#### Datasource, data

The *xls* file (*flights.xls*) contains data like this:

[image]

The cells in *Departure* and *Duration* columns have *Text* format (without any patterns).

#### Datasource, configuration

The *Excel* datasource have configuration (in *iReport*, you can do the same with *Java* code):

[image]

The Date format is set as *`yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm`* for reading data from *Departure* column of *Excel* file.

It is impossible to declare several fields of *`java.util.Date`* for *Excel datasource* which contains *Date* data with different patterns.
This behavior is determined by implementation  [*net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXlsDataSource.getFieldValue(JRField)*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRXlsDataSource.html#getFieldValue%28net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRField%29) method. You can see the source code of this class and you can change this behavior.

#### Template

The fields in report will be:

```xml
<field name="Flight" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Departure" class="java.util.Date"/>
<field name="Duration" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

Note that the *Duration* field has *java.lang.String* type.

The *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="flights" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="827d6b81-9342-48fd-88b5-f9ea2cfd8bfb">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="Flight" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Departure" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <field name="Duration" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="ccfc5f9d-0b0f-4127-be62-3c3eefc16c5e" mode="Opaque" x="273" y="0" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#999999"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Duration]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="5f7a483c-2c9b-456e-8d6e-3063534c1710" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="173" height="20" backcolor="#999999"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Flight]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="45724e54-4a70-48b1-980e-acbba6266670" mode="Opaque" x="173" y="0" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#999999"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Departure]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="a45c9487-3521-4440-8c4d-c016023dc799" x="0" y="0" width="173" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Flight}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm">
                <reportElement uuid="ad60f65d-72ba-48d3-bf3e-0d4275edabb4" x="173" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Departure}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="b20e0e58-feab-47f9-9ce8-63d89425e914" x="273" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Duration}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

#### Output result

The result will be (via preview in *iReport*):

[image]

*Notes*:

- I've used the *iReport 5.1.0*.
- You can change the format of *Duration* field with help of [*java.text .DateFormat.format(Date date)*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29) method. You can the example in [mysql datetime format change using java for JasperReports generation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9494093/876298) post.
- The format defined in datasource is applied only for *Departure* field.